# MySQL JOIN two talbles

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I hate asking for code but I just can't seem to do the below -

Staff

```
   | lastname  - name    - position |
   | Henderson | John    |  A       |
   | Howard    | Bob     |  B       |
   | Hendry    | Chris   |  B       |
```

Max_person

```
   | lastname  - change  |
   | Henderson | John    |
   | Howard    | Bob     |
   | Hendry    | Chris   |
```

I have been trying to JOIN these 2 tables - adding the "POSITION" column of staff to the end of max_person.

What is the query to use here?

Comment: You can delete questions, with no penalty, by clicking the delete link.  It's found to the left of your username/gravatar, under the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT mp.*,
       s.position
  FROM MAX_PERSON mp
  JOIN STAFF s ON s.name = mp.change
              AND s.lastname = mp.lastname
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select mp.lastname, mp.change, s.position
from Staff s
inner join Max_person mp on s.lastname = mp.lastname  
    and s.name = mp.change
```